# Using Moq.It.IsAny to test a string starts with something

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

Is it possible to use Moq to say a method accepts a string that starts with "ABC" for example.

As an example something like this:

```
logger.Verify(x => x.WriteData(Moq.It.IsAny<string>().StartsWith("ABC")), Times.Exactly(3));
```

That wont compile but hopefully it illustrates my point

Answer (score 68, accepted):

try:

```
logger.Verify(x => x.WriteData(Moq.It.Is<string>(str => str.StartsWith("ABC"))), Times.Exactly(3));
```

you can see another example of It.Is:

```
// matching Func<int>, lazy evaluated
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Add(It.Is<int>(i => i % 2 == 0))).Returns(true);
```

that comes from Moq documentation: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: yea i use that all of the time

Comment: which string it will check for starts with ? what is the input ?

Answer (score 11):

Try using:

```
Moq.It.Is<string>(x => x.StartsWith("ABC"))
```